# Accessing a nested multi-dimensional array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays. Here's the first:

```
$scope.selection = {
  "carrots",
  "celery",
  "corn",
  "apples",
  "bananas"
};
```

Here's the second:

```
$scope.shipment = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "vegetables",
    "manifest": [{"carrots", "celery", "corn"}]
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "produce",
    "manifest": [{"apples", "carrots", "bananas"}]
}];
```

I'd like to be able to see if a match exists in the second array as I iterate through the first. So far, I can use jQuery `inArray`to match an indexed item in the second array:

```
if ($.inArray($scope.shipment.manifest[0], $scope.selection) < 0) { console.log($scope.shipment.id) };

// for "carrots"
=> "0"
```

But since "carrots" is in two index positions in the shipment array, the above will only return the first shipment id.

How can I get both shipments?

Comment: You could use the .filter function in javascript. That will return all elements matching your expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your object `selection` is not valid.

Objects are key-value pairs, and you only have strings insde it. It probably should be an array.

Second, the same happens with the objects inside the property `manifest`. They also must be arrays.

When fixing your code, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve what you want:

```
var result = $scope.shipment.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.manifest.indexOf(item) >= 0;
});
```

Look at the snipped I've created below:

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.selection = [
  "carrots",
  "celery",
  "corn",
  "apples",
  "bananas"
];

$scope.shipment = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "vegetables",
    "manifest": ["carrots", "celery", "corn"]
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "produce",
    "manifest": ["apples", "carrots", "bananas"]
}];

var html = '';

$scope.selection.forEach(function(item, i) {
  var result = $scope.shipment.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.manifest.indexOf(item) >= 0;
  });
  
  html +=
    '<div>' +
      '<span>Item: ' + item + '</span>' + 
    '</div>' +
    '<div>' +
      '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre>' +
    '</div>';
});

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realize what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.shipment` is an array that doesn't have a property `manifest` but the  elements of that array are objects that do have that property

Try

```
$.inArray($scope.shipment[0].manifest[0], $scope.selection)
```

As mentioned there are simpler ways but I wanted to point out the problem

Comment: This kept getting me back to the same issue I had before. It was only calling the first manifest.